# Intriguing Question about Total Derivatives, and Gradients of function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

If I given $z=f(x,y)$, and I am asked to find the total derivative, and gradient of the functions the answers are slightly similar is there a particular reason why?

\begin{align}dz&=f_xdx+f_ydy\\ \nabla z&=f_x \hat{i}+f_y\hat{j}\end{align}

I can imagine that this works for a four space function as well:
\begin{align}dw&=f_xdx+f_ydy+f_zdz \\ \nabla w&= f_x\hat{i}+f_y\hat{j}+f_z\hat{z}\end{align}

Could anybody explain how this relationship is possible, and better yet the connection, because I attempted a problem where I had to find the gradient, and I had the function. 1st I took the total derivative then I set the $\hat{i}$, and $\hat{j}$ terms, and the answer matched the textbook solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the directional derivative,
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(w+hw') - f(w)}{h} = \nabla f(w) \cdot w'
$$
where $\nabla = (\partial/\partial w_1, ..., \partial/\partial w_n)$ is the gradient.

If you replace $w'$ with some arbitrarily small step along the principal axes, $(dx,dy,dz)$, you get the differential $dz$, $\nabla f(z) \cdot dz$.  If you substituted $w'$ as the matrix $[\array{i &j &k}]$, you get the notation that I personally associate with physics and very boring calculus problems.

But in the end, both notations are essentially just directional derivatives.  In the direction $w'$, how is the function changing, when $w'$ is just the principal axes?  Of course, $w'$ could be other things, and that's why the directional derivative is a very useful concept, in optimization (necessary conditions, variational inequalities) and function spaces (Frechet, Gateaux derivatives).

Comment: I personally love math, and found it so interesting because we didn't go over the limit definitions in my class because they were taught to be to difficult for our class aka Calculus 3. To me its baloney because the nitty gritty math so far as I have seen occurs at the limits definitions of the derivatives and other operations.

Comment: Spivak has a book that is very short called "Calculus on Manifolds" that might work for you, as a calc 3 student.  Serge Lang has a very long book called "Undergraduate Analysis" (and a "sequel" called "Real and Functional Analysis").  Otherwise, the next step is to go beyond calc to real analysis, which starts with something like Bartle & Sherbert, Rudin's Principles book, or Royden.  The classic Calculus books by Apostol are pretty great in my opinion, and do a better job of bridging the gap between calculus and analysis.

Comment: Another much more recent book which bridges this gap well is Fitzpatrick, "Advanced Calculus".